# SELECT using a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

Good Afternoon

I am new to SQL Server an strugling to build up my select. I was looking for some advice as I dont know where to turn.

So I have a table that I need to update if the columns exist in other tables. However the other table could just have a defualt value of 999, which mean any value. I will try and write the sudo code.

```
select row
from master table
where between dates
and cust is in ( custtable where cust matches or cust from custtable = 999)
and branch is in ( branchtable where branch matches or branch from branchtable = 999)
and product is in ( producttable where product matches or product from producttable = 999)
```

only if the 3 equate to being found should I have the row.

Please let me know you you require any more information as it may not have made sense

Thanks in advance. Go easy on me sa I am just learning

**UPDATE**

So I Have the following

```
select @SI_Id = SIC_IdSupportedInitiative, @SI_SuppId = SIC_IdSupplier,
 @sd = SIC_StartDate, @ed = SIC_EndDate, @SI_Amt = SIC_ClaimAmount
from SIC_SupportedInitiative
where SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = 1

select sc.ID, sc.[Actual Posting Date],sc.[Customer Account], 
 sc.[Accounting Branch],sc.[Product Code],sc.[SalesQ uantity],sc.SIC_TotalClaimAmount
From SalesCurrent sc
where sc.[Actual Posting Date] between @sd and @ed
and exists 
( select 1 from SIC_CustomerDetails c
    where c.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = @SI_id
      and c.SIC_ICC_Customer = sc.[Customer Account] or c.SIC_ICC_Customer = 999 )
and exists
( select 1 from SIC_BranchDetails b
    where b.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = @SI_id
      and b.SIC_IMO_Branch = sc.[Accounting Branch] or b.SIC_IMO_Branch = 999 )
and exists
( select 1 from SIC_ProductDetails p
    where p.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = @SI_id
      and p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code] or 
          p.SIC_SupplierProductCode IN (SELECT sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode 
                                          FROM SIC_SupplierProducts sp 
                                         WHERE sp.SIC_IdSupplier = @SI_SuppId 
                                           AND sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code])
)

then I was going to loop round as I need to update the SIC_TotalClaimAmount 

to be SIC_TotalClaimAMount = SIC_TotalClaimAmount + ( sc.[Sales Quantity] * @SI_Amt )
```

Again if there is an easier way would love to hear.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to update your table, why are you using a `select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what the rest of the query looks like, but you can do the logic you ware looking for using `exists`:

```
from mastertable mt
where between dates and
      exists (select 1 from custtable c where c.cust = mt.cust or c.cust = 999) and
      exists (select 1 from branchtable b where b.branch = mt.branch or b.branch = 999) and
      exists (select 1 from producttable p where p.product = mt.product or p.product = 999)
```

Comment: Thats fantastics. Thank you so much.

One last question. On The product table if the product is 999 then It should check another table to see if the row exists?

Again Thank you.

Comment: @Sip . . . That is another question.  Questions should be asked as questions, rather than in comment.  I would suggest that in the new question, you include sample data and desired results.